# Balancing toy interest and value with noise

Tags: infant, development, toys

We got the Poppin' Park Elefun Busy Ball Poppers toy. Our daughter loves the toy and it is really encouraging her to crawl and even to work on getting from her tummy to sitting to put the balls back in. I think it is a great toy, however it is VERY loud. I am not talking about the music, that does not bother me, the fan to blow the balls out is so loud that it quickly annoys me and drowns out that there even is music. I find myself wanting to take the toy away but she really has not been interested enough in anything else to try to get back to sitting once she goes to her tummy. Any suggestions for how to balance what seem to be some developmental benefits with the annoyance of the toy? Are there ways to encourage her to play with the toy and work on getting back to sitting without the noise of the fan?

Comment: I agree.  I hate noisy toys and in fact go out of my way not to buy anything that makes noise.  However, now that you have the toy and you see how great it is for your daughter I understand why you have a problem.

Comment: Have you tried earplugs?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, once Pandora's box has been opened, and a noisy tool has been discovered inside, there is no turning back...

Taking a new toy away from a baby can be quite difficult, and is prone to raise even higher levels of noise, because the baby will complain loudly. On the other hand, a new toy gets old rather quickly, so after a few days your child's attention will be focused on other toys.

My advice: Live through it, it will be over soon.